# Show that there does not exist a continuous map $\text{Sqrt} : S_1 \to S_1$ such that $\text{Sq} \circ \text{Sqrt} = Id_{S_1}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $S_1 =\{z:|z|=1\}$. Consider the map $\text{Sq} : S_1 \to  S_1$ given by 
$\text{Sq}(z) = z^2$.

> Show that there does not exist a continuous map $\text{Sqrt} : S_1 \to  S_1$ such that $\text{Sq} \circ \text{Sqrt} =
> Id_{S_1}$. (where  $(\text{Sq}(w))^2 = w.$).

I am unable to find any way how to approach the given problem;Please give some hints.

Comment: Look at the induced maps in homology ($H_1(S^1)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\operatorname{Sqrt}$ is a continuous function with the indicated property.

Then the function $\,f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}\,$ defined by setting $\,f(\theta) = e^{-i\theta/2}\operatorname{Sqrt}(e^{i\theta})$ is continuous.

But, for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R},$ $f(\theta)^2=e^{-i\theta}\,e^{i\theta}=1,$ so each $f(\theta)=\pm 1.$ The range of $\,f$ on the connected set $\mathbb{R}$ must be connected, so the range of $\,f$ must be either $\{1\}$ or $\{-1\}.$

It follows that either $\operatorname{Sqrt}(e^{i\theta})=e^{i\theta/2}$ for all $\theta$ or $\operatorname{Sqrt}(e^{i\theta})=-e^{i\theta/2}$ for all $\theta,$ but neither of these equations is compatible with the fact that  $\operatorname{Sqrt}(e^{i\cdot 0})=\operatorname{Sqrt}(e^{i\cdot 2\pi}),$ which is true since $e^{i\cdot 0}=1=e^{i\cdot2\pi}.$

Comment: I have one question ;how did you come with such a function as the choice of the function got the job  done

Comment: The value of Sqrt at each point $e^{i\theta}$ is $e^{i\theta/2}$ or $-e^{i\theta/2};$ those are the only square roots of $e^{i\theta}.$ By continuity, whichever one of these functions is equal to Sqrt at one point should also be equal to Sqrt at neighboring points, so you can make your way around the circle and the choice of $e^{i\theta/2}$ or $-e^{i\theta/2}$ will never change. But the value of either of those functions is different at $\theta=2\pi$ from $\theta=0.$ To formalize this, the easiest way of getting from $\pm e^{i\theta/2}$ to $\pm 1$ is just to multiply by $e^{-i\theta/2}.$